# What custom fees will a Canadian citizen pay on jewellery they bring into Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, import-taxes

I have a few questions, please:

1. Is it possible to pay custom fees on the spot upon arrival in Canada?
2. If the goods are related to a small jewellery business, how do you estimate the associated fees? I need to know the way to calculate such fees before making the purchase.
3. What information and documents are required to show with the goods?
4. Is it necessary to be the business owner in order to bring such goods for a business?

Comment: Have you researched eg https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/import/guide-eng.html

Comment: If this is for a business, then I would humbly posit that asking a bunch of random Internet strangers (which is what we and this site really are) is NOT the best way to go about this. You're going to want to talk to people who know the business/commercial laws for your locality. For Example, if one of us were to tell you import duty is 40% and you pay that... what if it turned out that businesses are only required to pay 30%, or more importantly, 50%. One is a loss of money, the other, possible jail time or heavy penalties.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about import/export and not travel.